# Padding on TableViewCell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I want to add padding to my table view cells. Thought I could do something like this but that didnt work.

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath  *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell * cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    return cell.frame.size.height + 20;
}
```

Comment: So how does the tableView show up as? Screenshots? Do you want to add bottom padding to the text/content in the cell?

Comment: What do you mean by Padding ?

Comment: No Bourne, I want more space above the text and more space below the text.
Exactly like padding work in a Html table cell.

Comment: see my answer. got your question.

Comment: I use that code snippet every single time I need variable heights for my cells with proper alignment and padding. But my requirements thus far have been text/label only. Suit it to your style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the below link. Explains the basics of getting a variable height (for cells) UITableView along with proper padding that your require. Example just includes text. Change it to suit your requirements within the cell.

http://www.cimgf.com/2009/09/23/uitableviewcell-dynamic-height/

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you placed this method in your delegate? it also depends on which cells. There are other methods...

```
// UITableViewDelegate Method
- (CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
    {
    }

// UITableViewDelegate Method
- (CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
    {
    }
```

also, if you are using the contentView of the cell then you will need to change the frame of your custom view

Answer (score 0):

When adding your cells you will need to set the y value of the cell's frame to half your padding to make it start at the right place. Also ensure that the cell does not have flexible height or it will expand to fill the height of the row.